# JOIN + Subselect over M:N table

Tags: sql-server

I have four tables `Product`, `Packaging`, `LabelsForPackaging` and `Label`

I need to query all Products with their Packaging and Labels (should result in multiple rows)

Product has `Packaging1Id` and `LabelsForPackaging` has the `PackagingId` and the `LabelId`.

I tried this

```
select * from Product
left join Packaging on Product.Packaging1Id = Packaging.Id
left join
(
    select * from LabelsForPackaging 
    inner join Label on LabelsForPackaging.LabelId = Label.Id
    where LabelsForPackaging.PackagingId = -- what to use here?
) as P
on Product.Packaging1Id = P.Id
```

If I try to use `where LabelsForPackaging.PackagingId = Packaging.Id` in the subselect, I get this error:

`The multi-part identifier "Packaging.Id" could not be bound.`

Comment: @McNets Thanks, this did the trick. Please post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just omit the `WHERE...` clause altogether? And then just `JOIN` all relevant tables as in:

```
SELECT * FROM Product
    LEFT JOIN Packaging
        ON Product.PackagingID = Packaging.ID
    LEFT JOIN LabelsForPackaging 
        ON LabelsForPackaging.PackagingID = Packaging.ID
    INNER JOIN Label
        ON LabelsForPackaging.LabelID = Label.ID
```